# PHPExcel Export for Larger Files fails

Tags: php, excel, export

I am using PHPExcel library to generate excel data based on mysql datbase. MySql query results in the 1,34,000 rows. And Excel Supports 65,536 Rows on one worksheet. So made logic like

```
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $val = array_values($value);

    if($rowscounter < 65000)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->addRow($val,$rowscounter);
    }
    else
    {
        $active_sheet++;
        $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($active_sheet);
        $rowscounter = 1;
    }
    $rowscounter++;
}
// deliver header   
header("Content-Type: $mtype; charset=" . $objPHPExcel->sEncoding);
header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $filename . ".$ext\"");

// Save it as an excel 2003 file
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,$objPHPExcel->sFileFormat);
//echo "Peak memory usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MB";exit;
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

to create new worksheet after 65000 records are reached for one woeksheet.

But it doesn't work; not giving any output or error. Initially I thought its because of memory limit. But when echoed it shows peak memory to 1400.5 MB and I have set my memory limit up to 3500MB using `ini_set('memory_limit', '3500M');`

Could you please suggest something or any alternative?

Comment: Can you outline the changes that you've made to PHPExcel? You're referencing methods such as $objPHPExcel->addRow() (which I'd expect to be associated with a worksheet rather than a workbook) and properties like $objPHPExcel->sFileFormat that aren't part of the PHPExcel library code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to determine if it's failing in the foreach() loop, or when trying to write the file?

Comment: Yes Mark, $objPHPExcel->addRow() is my function which is nothing but uses ->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow();

Comment: Yes $objPHPExcel->sFileFormat is not part of PHPExcel. Its custom variable. And above code is working perfectly for 10,000 records.

Comment: You reckon that it isn't memory - although my rule of thumb estimate is 1k per cell (columns x rows) * 2 + 25MB - but other possibilities include hitting a timeout limit.

Comment: Whats the execution time the script runs for? PHP has a limit on this as well, you might want to increase this if your script takes a while to execute

Comment: Hi Mark, So far I tried to debug and after 65000 rows system gave out of memory error. PHPExcel itself has memory leak issue for handling such a huge data.

Answer (score 2):

You might be exceeding the 65,000 limit, what do you set the $rowscounter initial value at? 1 or 0 (zero)? The reason I ask it that the array results starts at index 0 (zero), you're adding the row and then incrementing the counter after the add. So if you start the counter at 0 (zero) than you might have more rows that what you have counted. Also you are missing a row in the else statement, you loop through a value but don't add it to the sheet

try this

```
$rowscounter = 1;

foreach($result as $value)
{
    $val = array_values($value);

    if($rowscounter < 65000)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->addRow($val,$rowscounter);
    }
    else
    {
        $active_sheet++;
        $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($active_sheet);
        $rowscounter = 1;

        // add missing row
        $objPHPExcel->addRow($val,$rowscounter);
    }
    $rowscounter++;
}
// deliver header   
header("Content-Type: $mtype; charset=" . $objPHPExcel->sEncoding);
header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $filename . ".$ext\"");

// Save it as an excel 2003 file
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,$objPHPExcel->sFileFormat);
//echo "Peak memory usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MB";exit;
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

a simple example of what I'm trying to explain, if $i is set to 0 (zero) the else condition is not met. So you will have an extra row in your results. If $i is set to 1 the else condition is met

```
$count = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$i=1; // set this to 0 (zero) and test, set to 1 and test

foreach($count as $cnt) {
    if($i < 10) {
        echo "If condition - Count value: ".$cnt." i value:".$i."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Else condition - Count value: ".$cnt." i value:".$i."<br />";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Phill,Yes I missed row. Thanks to identify logical mistake. Now problem is of memory issue. As it is taking too longer to display anything, its difficult to determine exact amount of memory for it. I tried to assign 35000M, but still no effect.

Comment: Found a interesting thread about PHPExcel being the issue for the memory leak: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=18404 it does have a workaround